# Как преобразовать дату и время в unix на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, utc

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как преобразовать дату `2019-12-24 04:00:00` в UNIX GMT `1577160000` на Python.

Comment: У вас есть строка `2019-12-24 04:00:00` и из нее нужно получить `1577160000`, правильно?

Comment: У меня получилось 1577149200 - это ваше лакальное время, а нужно по Гринвичу

Comment: У вас есть строка 2019-12-24 04:00:00 и из нее нужно получить 1577160000, правильно? - да

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно через [.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) указать часовой пояс на `UTC`:

```
import datetime as DT    
...

dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=DT.timezone.utc)
print(dt)
print(dt.timestamp())
print(int(dt.timestamp()))
# 2019-12-24 04:00:00+00:00
# 1577160000.0
# 1577160000
```

Способы парсинга строки с датой:

```
import datetime as DT
dt = DT.datetime.strptime('2019-12-24 04:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(dt)
print(dt.timestamp())
print()
# 2019-12-24 04:00:00
# 1577142000.0

dt = DT.datetime.fromisoformat('2019-12-24 04:00:00')
print(dt)
print(dt.timestamp())
print()
# 2019-12-24 04:00:00
# 1577142000.0
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а как можно использовать вот этот вариант, только чтобы время было по Гринвичу, а не лакальное `dt = DT.datetime.fromisoformat('2019-12-24 04:00:00')
print(dt)
print(dt.timestamp())
print()`

Comment: потому что самый первый вариант выдает ошибку.

Comment: @ChikChirik, у меня первый вариант не выдает ошибку. В ответе есть решение, смотрите внимательнее, через `replace` выдает тоже время, что вы писали в вопросе. А UTC по смыслу тот же GMT

Comment: TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments такое выдает

Comment: dt = "2019-12-24 04:00:00"
                dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=DT.timezone.utc)
                print(dt)
                print(dt.timestamp())
                printnt(int(dt.timestamp()))

Comment: @ChikChirik, а у вас какая версия питона? :) Вообще, если это не работает, можно попробовать сделать так: `dt = dt.replace(None, None, None, None, None, None, None, DT.timezone.utc)`, по идеи, 8-м параметром и будет часовой пояс

Comment: Версия 3.7.1 :)

Comment: @ChikChirik, странно, а мне показалось что 2.7 ... Так, стоп... а почему вы у строки вызываете `replace`? Нужно у даты вызывать

Comment: `TypeError: replace() takes at most 3 arguments (8 given)` это если так: `dt = dt.replace(None, None, None, None, None, None, None, DT.timezone.utc)`

Comment: Сначала вы парсите строку в дату (например, `dt = DT.datetime.fromisoformat('2019-12-24 04:00:00')`), потом у объекта даты в `dt` вызываете `replace`

Comment: Да, Вы правы, теперь все получилось) Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: @ChikChirik, хех :)